# Javascript variables declared and initialized but give undefined when checked

Tags: javascript, variables

The following are the variables i have declared in javascript script tag.
The Variables are declared globally and initialized in the inner function which is inside another function (outer).

The problem is; when i try to check the variables using console.log i get "undefined". I don't know why.

I have read the variable hoisting, scope etc of Javascript variables. But i am unable to solve it. Please help.

```
                      var width;
                      var height;
                      var ratio;
                      var nwidth;
                      var nheight;
                      var wbool;
                      var imgsrc;
                      var canvas;

    $("#myimage").change(function(){
            readURL(this);
        });


    function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                      var image = new Image();
                      image.src = e.target.result;

                      image.onload = function(){
                            if(this.width > this.height){
                                ratio = this.width/this.height;
                                nheight = parseInt(Math.ceil(1024/ratio));
                                wbool = true;
                            }
                            else{
                                ratio = this.height/this.width;
                                window.nwidth = parseInt(Math.ceil(768*ratio));
                                wbool = false;                                                                  
                            }
                      }
                    console.log(window.nwidth + "" + wbool);
```

Comment: `image.onload` is asynchronous. Your console likely logs before the image is finished loading.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cpmdxos8/ it has errors...

Comment: no brother @Thomas , these are errors because i pasted a snippet from my project. i have closed the braces properly, the problem actually i am facing i why can't i change the value of nwidth which is initialized in the function and why i am getting undefined outside that function.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan, Sorry to say dear, but i don't know about "asynchronous". And i am just trying to change values of variables that are not related to image.......

Comment: @NaveedBaigJokhio please see my answer. You're getting undefined because you're trying to read the variable before it has been defined, since it is an async operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `console.log()`'ing `nwidth` before it has been assigned.

image.onload is an asynchronous operation (think like a callback). the console.log() is firing before the variable data has been assigned.

Try moving the log into the onload function.

```
                  var width;
                  var height;
                  var ratio;
                  var nwidth;
                  var nheight;
                  var wbool;
                  var imgsrc;
                  var canvas;

$("#myimage").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });


function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                  var image = new Image();
                  image.src = e.target.result;

                  image.onload = function(){
                        if(this.width > this.height){
                            ratio = this.width/this.height;
                            nheight = parseInt(Math.ceil(1024/ratio));
                            wbool = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            ratio = this.height/this.width;
                            window.nwidth = parseInt(Math.ceil(768*ratio));
                            wbool = false; 
                            // it will be defined here, because you are doing
                            // it inside the async operation.
                            console.log(window.nwidth);                       
                        }
                  }
                // this will be undefined, because the var has not been set
                // by the time this line executes.
                console.log(window.nwidth + "" + wbool);
```

**why does this happen?**

async operations, like ajax calls ( or file loading in your code), take time to complete. Since javascript runs on a single thread, if the app were to stop and wait for the operation to complete, then the browser would lock up. Not good!

So, async operations are skipped over, and the callback portion is executed once the operation completes. This means your code is executing like this:

1. start loading the file
2. console.log() // undefined
3. loading complete, and the variable has been defined.

To trigger a custom event, you could do something like this:

```
$("#myimage").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });

    // SET UP LISTENER FOR YOUR CUSTOM EVENT
    $(document).on('fileWasLoaded', function () {
        console.log(window.nwidth + "" + wbool);
    });


function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                  var image = new Image();
                  image.src = e.target.result;

                  image.onload = function(){
                        if(this.width > this.height){
                            ratio = this.width/this.height;
                            nheight = parseInt(Math.ceil(1024/ratio));
                            wbool = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            ratio = this.height/this.width;
                            window.nwidth = parseInt(Math.ceil(768*ratio));
                            wbool = false; 
                            // TRIGGER YOUR CUSTOM EVENT WHEN THE IMAGE IS LOADED
                            $(document).trigger('fileWasLoaded');                 
                        }
                  }
```

Comment: somehow i am getting what you are trying to say. should i console.log inside timeout function with some delay.....???

Comment: That is one way to do it, however you don't know how long the operation might take, so it's not fool proof. I recommend reading into Promises, which were invented to solve this sort of problem, or you could broadcast an event when the operation completes, and listen for that event before console.log().

Comment: Dear can you please tell me how can i broadcast event to listen to it... If i am not wrong like passing event to image.onload = function(event) like that???

Comment: @NaveedBaigJokhio I've edited the answer. Look into custom events with jQuery, and `.trigger()` to trigger them.

Comment: You're welcome, @NaveedBaigJokhio . :) If my answer helped you, I'd appreciate if you marked it as the answer. Thanks!